# Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

Есть написанный тест на java. Там три теста и прописано так, что на каждый тест открывается новый браузер. Тесты проверяют нажатие линков.

Как прописать, чтобы браузер открывался один раз и после прохождения теста снова был возврат на исходную страницу?

Comment: а можно код теста(хотя бы часть с открытием браузера) привести для наглядности?

Comment: Прошу прощения, что сразу не ответил))) Разобрался)

Comment: можете сами записать ответ под своим вопросом - поможете тем кто столкнулся с такой же проблемой ;-)

Comment: В моем случае я решил проблему, поместив все, что нужно выполнить, в один тест, а в конце указал переход на исходный URL.